# Can't connect to Hyper-V server

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019, hyper-v-manager

I've got two computers, one server running Windows Server 20H2, and a client using Windows 10 Pro. I've installed Hyper-V on the server and want to connect to the Hyper-V server using Hyper-V Manager on the client.

According to several guides/blogs/docs/etc I found online the following steps should be enough:

The steps I've done so far on server

1. `PS> Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools -Restart`
2. `PS> Enable-PSRemoting`
3. `PS> Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server`

On the client:

1. Add entry in hosts file `192.168.0.2 my-server.internal.my-domain.com` with IP of the server
2. `PS> Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer "my-server.internal.my-domain.com"`
3. `PS> Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts "my-server.internal.my-domain.com" -Force`
4. `PS> cmdkey /add:my-server.internal.my-domain.com /user:Administrator /pass:<password>`
5. Enabled `Allow delegating fresh credentials with NTLM-only server authentication` group policy and added `wsman/my-server.internal.my-domain.com` to the server list

After doing all this I still get the following error dialog:

[image: Error message]

Some things to note:

- Running powershell remote works fine (e.g. `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName my-server.internal.my-domain.com`), so authentication with WinRM seems to be working
- I've also tried opening port 5985 manually in the firewall on both client and server

Comment: Can you can [edit] your question and include the error message you received?

Comment: Try adding my-server again to the various without the .internal.my-domain.com suffix.  I've never needed to add the entry in the client hosts file, but I've always added my-server and my-server.my-domain.com

Comment: @Ramhound the image with the error should now be visible.

Comment: @essjae I'll try that, I think I've done it more or less already. I also tried wildcards like * and *.internal.my-domain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working, to solve it I needed to enabled WinRM correctly on the client by:

1. Open Local Group Policy manager on PC (gpedit.msc)
2. Go to `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Remote Management (WinRM) -> WinRM Client`
3. Enable `Trust the remote machine` and add the hostname, or as I did for testing enable all by using `*`
4. I also enabled the policies `Allow Basic authentication`, `Allow CredSSP authentication`, and `Allow unencrypted traffic` here

Then when connecting in Hyper-V manager I had to use the computer name of the server, not the dns name.